# Convert object values to enum-like type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The type of `ParsedParametersObject["--mode"]` must be one of `Parameters[ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject].mode.values`. Currently it has been hardcoded, so when new supported mode will be added to application we need to edit both `Parameters[ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject].mode.values` and `ParsedParametersObject`.

How I can convert `Parameters[ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject].mode.values` to valid enum-like type?

```js
enum ValidFirstCommandPhrases {
 initializeProject = "initializeProject",
 buildProject = "buildProject"
}

export const Parameters = {
    [ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject]: {
      mode: {
        name__includingDoubleNDash: "--mode",
        values: {
          development: "development",
          production: "production",
        }
      },
      debug: {
       name__includingDoubleNDash: "--debug"
     }
  }
} as const;

type ParsedParametersObject = {
    // --mode
  [Parameters[ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject].mode.name__includingDoubleNDash]:
    "development" | "production"; // Hardcoded!!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option you can use is to have a dedicated `ENVIRONMENTS` enum and use it as a type in `ParsedParametersObject["--mode"]`'s type.

See below

```js
enum ValidFirstCommandPhrases {
 initializeProject = "initializeProject",
 buildProject = "buildProject"
}

enum ENVIRONMENTS {
    DEVELOPMENT = 'development',
    PRODUCTION = 'production'
}

export const Parameters = {
    [ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject]: {
      mode: {
        name__includingDoubleNDash: "--mode",
        values: {
          development: ENVIRONMENTS.DEVELOPMENT,
          production: ENVIRONMENTS.PRODUCTION,
        }
      },
      debug: {
       name__includingDoubleNDash: "--debug"
     }
  }
} as const;

type ParsedParametersObject = {
    // --mode
  [Parameters[ValidFirstCommandPhrases.buildProject].mode.name__includingDoubleNDash]: 
ENVIRONMENTS;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It will! Thank you for the answer!